# users and shares on external partition

Tags: partitioning, users, raid, format

I have tried my upmost to get this working and have lost the will to live but am not going to give up!

Basically, I have 1 SSD which I have just installed Ubuntu 14.4.01 on fresh and I have created a RAID1 array on the motherboards controllers mirroring 2 WD 2TB drives. This I can see in the "Disks" util. Currently it is unformatted.

I am slowly understanding that "/" is the mother of all directories and everything else sits under that. I attempted to create a separate /home on the install which would have been on the mirror. I kept getting ??? ??? as the error though :-( even though I setup a swap and / on the SSD.

That all aside what I would like to do is format this mirror so that all users on the system can access this drive and can create folders. Once they have created folders I would like them to be able to control permissions so only they have access to them so they can be shared on the network with Win7/OSX and Ubuntu machines but from being logged in as them.

The issue I've been having is if I format the mirror under the first and only created user on the system it say's that only I have access to it and nothing else can. When I created two folders for home directories it created them but I could not login. So I created them on the SSD which logged me in fine. I then attempted to access the formatted mirror again and nobody else could access it still.

Moving on I formatted it in root which was great as everyone could see it but nobody could access it still. From my reading it looks like it has to be mounted at /media

I am stuck now and I'm sure somebody on here can do this in their sleep which I am currently depleted of. I am not sure on the professional way to do this.

All you help vey much appreciated so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is moving the `/home` folder to your RAID disk. In that way, users would have a directory (their $HOME directory) in which they could do everything they want.

In case you understand not fully how it works, Unix has a standard directory tree, created on installation under the root `/`. By default, all this is created on the boot disk or device, but you can dispatch those folders on different disks or partitions. These are permanent mountpoints, you can fetch them in the file `/etc/fstab`

The important point is the system needs these folders to work correctly. On the contrary, some disks or network shares can be added (mounted) on the system temporarily. These must be located somewhere in the directory tree, and most often, the `/media` folder is used for it. This folder is dedicated to temporary mounts like CDs or USB disks. But things like NFS shares can be mounted anywhere.

Now, if you want to create this configuration (`/home` folder on your RAID disk), the easiest and safest way is to do it during system installation. It can be done too on an existing installation, but it's a much more risky business.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer I forgot to respond. I went for the fresh install option and we were good to go! Been working ever since. :-)